# Java Maximum File Size

Tags: java, cross-platform

Is there an cross-platform way to determine the maximum file size of the host OS in Java?

Comment: the maximum file size is usually a function of the file system, rather than the OS. Most OSs can use 64-bits to represent file lengths/offsets, so in principle can support files up to 16 Exabytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, maximum file size is file system dependent. (you can see a comparison [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems)).
You can figure out the file system type using a platform specific manner (for example, mount on linux).

Answer (score 1):

The largest file is surely no larger than the amount of free space, which you can get via

```
long FileSystemUtils.freeSpaceKb(String path)
```

from Apache [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileSystemUtils.html#freeSpaceKb(java.lang.String))

On JDK 6, you can use [File.getFreeSpace()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getFreeSpace()) to find the free space of the partition containing the file.

Comment: This is untrue. There are (legacy) filesystems which can't create files as large as the entire disk. FAT32 for example has a file size limitation of 4GB. NTFS (and most other 64bits file systems) in turn have a theoretical limit of 16EB, but the practical limit is much lesser as well, 2TB. Nowadays disks/array-of-disks are easily that big.

Comment: Might even be possible to create files greater than free space on compressing file systems...